# How do I transfer page scroll input to a scrollable div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm brand new to JavaScript, so bear with me!

I have a webpage that has a scrollable div element.

I've been trying to find a solution that adds the following functionality:

A user scrolls down the page. Once the scrollable div element reaches the center of the viewport, scrolling input is switched from the page to the div - freezing the page scroll with the div vertically centered.

Once the div element reaches the end of its scrollable content, scroll input is returned to the overall page and the user can scroll past the div element.

Ideally, this mechanic would work when page scrolling down to or up to the scrollable div element.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're open to JavaScript libraries, then [GSAP ScrollTrigger](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/) is a good option to do what you wish. They have tutorials to follow and demos to review

Comment: stackoverflow is not a platform to write code for you.